# How mass of different components in a solution get affected in centrifugation process?

Tags: forces, density

Centrifugation technique is used in laboratory or even at home to separate colloidal solution with variable densities constituents.Example butter from milk

So **How does Centrifugation help in separating different densities components of a solution? Why high and less densities object form two different immiscible layer during this procedure that is how mass of components affect their separation?**

Answer (score 1):

It’s the density, not the mass, that matters.

In the rotating frame of reference, the “apparent gravity” that appears due to the (fictitious) centrifugal force will be many times higher than g.

Suspended particles are subject to gravity, buoyancy, and the individual impacts of other molecules in the liquid. For small particles in suspension, the tiny net force of gravity (gravity minus buoyancy) may be too small to overcome the effect of molecular impacts, so the particle remains suspended and subject to Brownian motion.

When you turn up the speed of centrifugation, you effectively “turn up gravity (and buoyancy)”. This makes it strong enough to cause drift (to either the inside or the outside, “top or bottom”) of particles. The higher the density difference compared to the suspending liquid, the greater the force moving the particles. This heavier particles will get to the bottom first while lightest particles will drift to the top.